# jquery: attributes of a .find() search

Tags: jquery, find

I'm getting started with JQuery and javascript in general and I'm running into an issue that I'm not understanding.  Assuming I have a table of data(let's say the id of the table is 'tbl') that has  elements, which may or may not have an 'orderasc' class associated with it (only 1  element can have this at any one time, but none have to have it).

I can check for the existence of an element with the 'orderasc' class using the following:

```
if($('#tbl th').is('.orderasc')) {
    //do something here
}
```

which works fine.  Inside of the if statement, I'm trying to alert the name attribute of the element that has the 'orderasc' class.  Trying the following does not work (shows undefined):

```
alert($('#tbl th').find('.orderasc').attr('name'));
```

but the following does:

```
alert($('#tbl').find('th.orderasc').attr('name'));
```

Likewise, when I modify my original if statement to this:

```
if($('#tbl').is('th.orderasc')) {
    //do something here
}
```

It does not work.
Can someone explain to me what's happening behind the scenes and giving me these results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$('#tbl th').find...` is recursively searching the DOM in the `th`, however your `th` is the element with the class.

To add to that the `find` function is recursive, and can be expensive. At least more expensive than the `children` function or using a psuedo class. I would recommend something like this instead:

```
alert($('#tbl th.orderasc:first').attr('name'));
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/durilai/Cav3Z/)

Comment: Good to know about the recursion taking place with find().  Thanks for the explanation and the tip!

Answer (score 0):

`.find()` searches the children inside that element. since the `th` has the class `orderasc` your selector: `$('#tbl th')` is already at the `th` and the `.find()` will look inside the `th` for the `orderasc` class.